# How to call this function in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

```
(defun (setf xwin-border-width) (width win)
    (setf (xlib:drawable-border-width win) width))
```

then how to call the above function ? In fact i donot really understand what "(setf xwin-border-width)" means in place of function time ?

Sincerely !

Comment: might be a good idea to include the language you are working in in the title of the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This defines a `setf` function. You can call it using `(setf (xwin-border-width *some-window*) width)`.

You might find the documentation for `setf` useful: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/m_setf_.htm

The Hyperspec also has a section on generalised references: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/05_a.htm

Answer (score 1):

By making the first argument to defun of this form `(setf f)`, you define what happens when the first argument to `setf` is a call to f.

```
(defun foo (lst) (car lst))

(defun (setf foo) (val lst)
  (setf (car lst) val))
```

The above pair of functions defines foo as a synonym for car. IN the definition of a function whose name is of the form `(setf f)`, the first parameter represents the new value, and the remaining parameters represent arguments to f.

Now any `setf` to `foo` will be a call to the latter function above:

```
? (let ((z (list 1 2 3)))
     (setf (foo z) 168)
     z)
(168 2 3)
```

Do not have to define `foo` in order to define `(setf foo), but they usually come in pairs.

Check chapter 6 Functions of ANSI Common Lisp by Paul Graham.